# Akka graph stream failed to produce output

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I am just playing with examples given on akka stream documentation page : http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.2/scala/stream/stream-graphs.html

Below example taken from there is not producing output. Can someone point out what is wrong here ?

Update : It is working from terminal. But failing in Intellij

My SBT dependencies are :

```
val akkaVersion = "2.3.7"
val httpVersion = "2.0.4"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.11",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-experimental" % httpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-core-experimental" % httpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-experimental" % httpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json-experimental" % httpVersion
)
```

Program :

```
import akka.stream.ClosedShape


object Test extends App {

  import akka.actor.ActorSystem
  import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
  import akka.stream.scaladsl._

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

  val source = Source(Stream.from(1))

  val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val zip = b.add(ZipWith((left: Int, right: Int) => left))
    val bcast = b.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
    val concat = b.add(Concat[Int]())
    val start = Source.single(0)

    source ~> zip.in0
    zip.out.map { s => println(s); s } ~> bcast ~> Sink.ignore
    zip.in1 <~ concat <~ start
    concat <~ bcast
    ClosedShape
  })

  graph.run()

  Thread.sleep(1000000)
}
```

Comment: What are you using to run this app? Works fine for me using SBT. You could try reducing the Source throughput by using (e.g.) `val source = Source(Stream.from(1)).delay(50 millis, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)`

Comment: It is woking from terminal but failing in intellij run.

Comment: As you already said, there is nothing wrong with the code. It's running without raising any error. Probably, some configurations in your intellij environment are wrong. If you provide the details(exceptions, error messages etc.), we can better help.